# Pair bluetooth device using flutter_reactive_ble

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am exploring the flutter bluetooth connectivity.
I am able to connect the device by using this flutter_reactive_ble plugin. But the device is not paired.
Is there any solution that I can pair the device also by using this plugin?

Comment: As far as I know I don't think you can. BLE or Bluetooth Low Energy has different technique and feature as standard Bluetooth. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) pairing is handled by the operating system and is only used if the accessed characteristic requires some security features.
*flutter_reactive_ble* should be able to work with devices that require pairing.

Comment: How can I do this programmatically?
In native android it has that feature to pair the device programmatically. 
Is it possible with flutter_reactive_ble?

Comment: I don't think there is a method for manual pairing in flutter_reactive_ble. Why do you need this?

Comment: I have a device, after pairing the device, the device is only connected.
If I pair the device from system's pairing options, then only it is connected. Instead of going to system's pairing options I want do this programmatically!

Comment: What kind of device is it? BLE device do not show up in the system settings most of the time, sometimes they do. You do not need to do anything in the system settings for BLE devices. Connecting programatically is enough to communicate. Pairing is only needed if you need security features and is handled by the OS. Your app will show a pairing request dialog inside your app if pairing is needed.